# How can I give access to a specific cube in PowerPivot?

Tags: ssas, powerpivot

This is my first time trying to grant access to one of my users to view a specific analysis cube via PowerPivot in Excel.

We are working with Excel 2010, I've created a local user on the server itself and add it to analysis from the SQL management studio.

I've created a role for this user and set a read permission only for a specific cube.

I've open Excel on my local computer > selected Data > From Other Source > From Analysis Services

Entered the server address and login details. Then I had 3 problems:

1. It shows me ALL the cubes and all databases that are available on the analysis server, WHY DOES IT HAVE A PERMISSION TO SELECT THEM?
2. After choosing the cube that I want I got this error: "An Error was encountered in the Transport layer", but when I clicked OK I got a "Multidimentional Connection 11.0" window that asked me for my login details again, and after I entered them it gave me access. HOW CAN I AVOIDE THIS ERROR?
3. After connecting to the cube and starting the work process, WHAT IS MY INDICATOR FOR KNOWING ON WHICH CUBE I'M WORKING ON?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you created a specific windows user account?

Comment: yes i did.. someone suggested me to define trusted domain because the user is working on a different domain than the server so i will consult with the IT guy. Thanks

Comment: Yeah that's inline with what I was thinking, let me know how it pans out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable the "Save Password" Option in the Connection Properties Definition Tab. If the user is a local user you have to do this.

To see on which cube you are working on, have a look on DATA/Properties.